# Error 404 at logging on phpmyadmin with Nginx

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

I have an error 404 when I connect me on Phpmyadmin on my server like:
http://url/phpmyadmin

I obtain the phpmyadmin page but when I click on "Execute", I obtain an error 404

On my default file on Nginx, sites-available, I add that:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    root /usr/share/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            root /usr/share/;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
    location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
            root /usr/share/;
            }
    }
    location /phpMyAdmin {
            rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
    }
```

Why I can't to connect ? Have I forgot to do an configuration?

Comment: No i can login sucessefully so when i'm login the page redirect to path from wpsXXX,wpx.och/indexpjp.php ?token=.....

Comment: Id a mannyaky inserst phpmyadmin between VPSXXX.OVH.CA AND INDEX.PHP?roken..... Ii'm always correct mhPhpMyAdmin wih=token=..,,, pHi have access to phpmyadmin without problem... It's only when i'm loggint from vpsXXX.vps.ovh.ca /phpadmin.index.php and login with a good credentiel i'm arrive to vpsXXX.vps.ovh.ca/index.php&index.pjp?token=00000, the patch of phpmyadmin disapear